# Difference Between Scream and Warning?

Tags: php, runtime-error, warnings

I am new in web, I want to know that Difference between a scream and warning as i am receiving them both on my page. And what should be our priority to remove first ?? And which of them can cause more trouble ? Are they part of each other ?

Comment: what is that "scream" you are talking about?

Comment: @YourCommonSense http://i.imgur.com/UDNWAyH.png You're supposed to scream at the screen when that happens XD

Comment: I should have recognized that. It's indeed in the xdebug docs, yet I've never seen it in action

Comment: I received "warning:" along with the "scream:"
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource.....
is this funny ?